# What does "the broken nose" mean here?

Tags: meaning, literature

I am wondering what "the broken nose" means in the following sentences:

> ‘Dad!’ I say, ‘You terrified poor Hannah!’ I mean it was a bit of an
> overreaction from her, dropping her glass like that. Did she really
> have to make such a scene? I stifle my annoyance as Aoife begins
> sweeping up the shards, moving discreetly around us with a broom.
>
> ‘Sorry.’ Dad grins at us all as he enters the room. ‘Thought I’d give
> ye all a little fright.’ His accent is more pronounced than usual,
> presumably as he’s on home turf, or nearly. He grew up in the
> Gaeltacht, the Irish-speaking part of Galway, not far from here. Dad’s
> not a big man but he manages to take up quite a bit of space and
> presents an imposing figure: the set of his shoulders, **the broken
> nose**. It’s difficult for me to see him objectively, because of what
> he is to me. But I suppose an outsider might assume he was a boxer or
> something similarly pugilistic, rather than a very successful property
> developer.

- Lucy Foley, *The Guest List*, Chapter 14

This is a thriller novel published in 2020 in the United Kingdom. One hundred and fifty guests would be gathering at some remote and deserted fictional islet called Inis an Amplóra off the coast of the island of Ireland to celebrate the wedding between Jules (a self-made woman running an online magazine called *The Download*) and Will (a celebrity appearing in a TV show program called *Survive the Night*). The day before the actual wedding day, to attend the rehearsal dinner, Jules' dad comes to the island. But he appears after surprising Hannah, who is standing close to the window, by making a scary face in the darkness from the outside of the window. Seeing her dad, Jules thinks that he has such an imposing figure.

In this part, I am wondering what "the broken nose" would mean here.

I first assumed that it might be similar to a "hooked nose," but, when I googled "broken nose," the search result showed that it could mean a nasal bone fracture, so I am confused.

I guess I am confused even more because, in the same paragraph, it is said that he has an appearance similar to a boxer or a person in a pugilistic profession, who could easily have a nose injury, as far as I know.

In short, I am wondering whether this "broken nose" would mean that his nose is shaped by being bent as in a hooked nose, or that his nose had once been fractured and recuperated. (There is no description in this novel regarding his bone fracture, though.)

Comment: I had a broken nose when I fell off a motorcycle in 1974. It is still bent and a bit flattened; people usually assume I got it in a fight.

Comment: Dear @MichaelHarvey, thank you very much for the comment. Oh no, that must have been so painful! So "broken nose" really means that a nose is broken. I sincerely appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broken nose is literal, but it means a nose that is bent due to it not healing straight.  It is often an indicator of someone who has been in fights in the past. But it can be caused by a fall or a traffic accident. It doesn't mean hooked nose.

[image] ([source](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/325075))

Answer (score 3):

A 'broken nose' is a nose that has been injured in a fight or accident, so that one or more bones in the nose have been broken or cracked. If the bone damage is not repaired by medical attention, the nose usually has a bent or distorted appearance.

[Nasal fracture (patient information leaflet)](https://www.royalberkshire.nhs.uk/patient-information-leaflets/AandE%20Nasal%20Fracture.htm)

[image]